# I cannot see EmailTemplate object while making a look up field in Account object?

Tags: email-template, lookup, account, send-email

In Account detail page I am trying to create a look up field name "SelectEmailTemplate" . But in the related object list i cannot see the object 'EmailTemplate'.... Any solution , thanks in Advance
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can manually insert the actual ID of the email template as a text string.

Although you can assign an email template to a workflow action, **you cannot** **have a Lookup** field in either a standard object or custom object that points to an email template.

See here  for more info -

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000HQ9QAAW